# Scrapy works in shell but spider returns empty csv

Tags: shell, csv, scrapy

I am learning Scrapy. Now I just try to scrapy items and when I call spider:

```
planefinder]# scrapy crawl planefinder -o /User/spider/planefinder/pf.csv -t csv
```

it shows tech information and no scraped content (Crawled 0 pages .... etc), and it returns an empty csv file.
The problem is when i test xpath in scrapy shell it works:

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> sel = Selector(response)
>>> flights = sel.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-12'][1]/div/div/table//tr")
>>> items = []
>>> for flt in flights:
...     item = flt.xpath("td[1]/a/@href").extract_first()
...     items.append(item)
... 
>>> items
```

The following is my planeFinder.py code:

```
# -*-:coding:utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector, HtmlXPathSelector
from planefinder.items import arr_flt_Item, dep_flt_Item


class planefinder(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'planefinder'
    host = 'https://planefinder.net'
    start_url = ['https://planefinder.net/data/airport/PEK/']


    def parse(self, response):
        arr_flights = response.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-12'][1]/div/div/table//tr")
        dep_flights = response.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-12'][2]/div/div/table//tr")   

        for flight in arr_flights:
            arr_item = arr_flt_Item()

            arr_flt_url = flight.xpath('td[1]/a/@href').extract_first()
            arr_item['arr_flt_No'] = flight.xpath('td[1]/a/text()').extract_first()
            arr_item['STA'] = flight.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract_first()
            arr_item['From'] = flight.xpath('td[3]/a/text()').extract_first()
            arr_item['ETA'] = flight.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract_first()

            yield arr_item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please before going to `CrawlSpider` please check the docs for [`Spider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html)s, some of the issues I've found were:

- Instead of `host` use `allowed_domains`
- Instead of `start_url` use `start_urls`
- It seem that the page needs to have some cookies set or maybe it's using some kind of basic anti-bot protection, and you need to land somewhere else first.

Try this (I've also changed a bit :

```
# -*-:coding:utf-8 -*-

from scrapy import Field, Item, Request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Spider

class ArrivalFlightItem(Item):
    arr_flt_no = Field()
    arr_sta = Field()
    arr_from = Field()
    arr_eta = Field()


class PlaneFinder(Spider):
    name = 'planefinder'
    allowed_domains = ['planefinder.net']
    start_urls = ['https://planefinder.net/data/airports']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield Request('https://planefinder.net/data/airport/PEK', callback=self.parse_flight)


    def parse_flight(self, response):
        flights_xpath = ('//*[contains(@class, "departure-board") and '
                         './preceding-sibling::h2[contains(., "Arrivals")]]'
                         '//tr[not(./th) and not(./td[@class="spacer"])]')

        for flight in response.xpath(flights_xpath):
            arrival = ArrivalFlightItem()
            arr_flt_url = flight.xpath('td[1]/a/@href').extract_first()
            arrival['arr_flt_no'] = flight.xpath('td[1]/a/text()').extract_first()
            arrival['arr_sta'] = flight.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract_first()
            arrival['arr_from'] = flight.xpath('td[3]/a/text()').extract_first()
            arrival['arr_eta'] = flight.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract_first()

            yield arrival
```

Comment: Thank you @Wilfredo, it works now! As a new Scrapy learner, I also want to know how to know if a page needs to have some cookies set or maybe it's using some kind of basic anti-bot protection".

Comment: hey @Kai.W you can inspect the sources/requests traffic, etc using the developer tools from your browser, you can also sniff the traffic using some proxy-like service and see exactly what's received/sent per webpage. If it behaves different in scrapy, curl, urllib, etc than in the browser (inspecting the html body) then it probably has some sort of protection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not understanding correctly which "Spider" to use, as `Scrapy` offers different custom ones.

The main one, and the one you should be using is the simple `Spider` and not `CrawlSpider`, because `CrawlSpider` is used for a more deep and intensive search into forums, blogs, etc.

Just change the type of spider to:

```
from scrapy import Spider

class plane finder(Spider):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of ROBOTSTXT_OBEY in your settings.py file. By default it's set to True (but not when you run shell). Set it to False if you wan't to disobey robots.txt file.